# Replace default prompt with own jquery beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

How to get rid of web browser default prompt?
My coffescript below.
[image]

```
$(window).on 'beforeunload', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    question = "<h4 class='text-center'>The actual changes for black/white list will be lost.</h4>"
    bootbox.confirm question, (result) ->
        if result
            $.post url, () ->
                window.location.reload()
```

Comment: You can't, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace the inbuilt message boxes. All you can do is use a plugin (or write your own logic) which replaces their functionality with HTML elements which can be styled.

This will mean changing your javascript code where `alert`, `confirm` etc are used.